# Swift: Enable or disable constraint bug

Tags: swift, constraints, gesture

I'm creating a gesture on a view that I called separatorView (in the photo it's the middle black view).

I use the constraint method and the priorities to do it:

-centerConstraint = This is the constraint that allows to center the view horizontally in X, priority = 1000

-rightConstant = This constraint links the view to the edge of the right screen at zero pt, priority = 999

-GaucheConstant = This constraint links the view to the edge of the left screen at zero pt, priority = 998

When I drag this view to the left, the animation continues to drag.

The problem is that after the animation is finished, and I want to resume the view and drag it to the left the cash application centerConstraint is nil!

I can not find the solution to make it all generic and I can slide the view to the right or left without any problem

I know the problem comes from the fact that I disable the constraint

[image: The photo]

here my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sep: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var constantGauche: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var constantDroite: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var startingConstant: CGFloat  = 0.0

var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesEnded = false
    sep.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture!)
}

@objc func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.centerConstraint.constant
    case .changed:
        self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.x
    case .ended:
        if translation.x > 0 {
            centerConstraint.isActive = false
            constantGauche.isActive = false
            constantDroite.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }else{
            centerConstraint.isActive = false
            constantGauche.isActive = true
            constantDroite.isActive = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you disable the center constraint, iOS removes it from the view's constraints and frees it because there is no longer a strong reference to it. The `@IBOutlet` is a `weak` reference which gets set to `nil` as soon as the strong references are all gone.  So the next time you access the center constraint, it crashes because it is `nil` and `centerConstraint` is *implicitly unwrapped* with `!`.

Instead of disabling constraints, modify their priorities:

- Change the center constraint priority to `999` as a starting value.  You'll get an error if you try to modify a required constraint's priority in code.
- Lowering the `priority` of the left and center constraints will cause `sep` to move to the right.  Once it gets there, you can calculate the new `constant` for the center constraint and then set their priorities back to the starting values.
- Lowering the `priority` of the right and center constraints will cause `sep` to move to the left.  Once it gets there, you can calculate the new `constant` for the center constraint and then set their priorities back to the starting values.

---

```
@objc func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.centerConstraint.constant
    case .changed:
        self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.x
    case .ended:
        if translation.x > 0 {
            centerConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
            constantGauche.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
        } else {
            centerConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
            constantDroite.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        print(sep.center.x - view.center.x)
        centerConstraint.constant = sep.center.x - view.center.x
        centerConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        constantGauche.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 998)
        constantDroite.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 998)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

---

Here are the changes running in the simulator:

[image: Image of separator in the simulator]